# eslint/eslint-plugin-react:not finding .jsx files

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint

I'm using `eslint` on a react app for the first time, and while it's checking .js files perfectly well, it's not finding any .jsx files. Admittedly my understanding is hazy, but I thought `eslint-plugin-react` automatically scanned .jsx files as well with `parserOptions.ecmaFeatures.jsx` set to true?

If I run `npm run:lint -- --ext .jsx` then jsx files are scanned correctly, but not with a default `npm run:lint` command

My .eslintrc here:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "es6":     true,
    "browser": true,
    "node":    true,
    "mocha":   true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
  "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like using the `--ext` CLI flag is the only way to specify file extensions. See the documentation below.

https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/user-guide/configuring#specifying-file-extensions-to-lint

One thing you could do is to include the flag as part of your npm command. For example, `npm run lint` could run `eslint --ext .jsx` so that you don't have to type it manually.